# MS Access VBA: turn query results into a single string

Tags: ms-access, vba, concatenation

I have a table in MS Access composed of items, and there's another table where salespeople tie into those items. So for example the item "pencil" could have 4 people that sold it associated. Once everything comes out of the query I have something like this:

```
item    seller
pencil  joe
pencil  bob
pencil  charles
pen     john
eraser  ruth
paper   charles
```

I have a report form where I'd like to list each item's sellers on a single line. Kind of like:

```
pencil: bob, joe, charles
pen:    john
eraser: ruth
paper: charles
```

I figure I can pound out a solution where I create an ADO Recordset object from a query statement filtered by item name, and then use a for each cycle to go through the records and feed the names into a concatenate string for each item. Sounds like the long way to do it though. Anyone have a better way of doing it?

Comment: Consider [ConcatRelated](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) and [previous SO posts about it](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bms-access%5D+concatrelated)

Answer (score 2):

You can create a query using Allen Browne's [ConcatRelated](http://allenbrowne.com/func-concat.html) function to concatenate the *seller* names for each *item* into a separate field.  And then use the query in your report's Record Source.

Here is the output from the query below with your sample data stored in a table named *YourTable*:

```
item    sellers
------  ------------------
eraser  ruth
paper   charles
pen     john
pencil  joe, bob, charles
```

```sql
SELECT
    y.item,
    ConcatRelated
        (
            "seller",
            "YourTable",
            "[item]='" & [y].[item] & "'"
        ) AS sellers
FROM YourTable AS y
GROUP BY y.item;
```

Answer (score 1):

Jet SQL doesn't natively support any mechanism for concatenating over a group.

However, you could issue a single query with all the data, and use a `Scripting.Dictionary` (**Tools** -> **References** -> **Microsoft Scripting Runtime**) to hold the results.

```
Dim dict As New Scripting.Dictionary
Do Until rs.EOF
    If Not dict.Exists(rs!item) Then dict(rs!item) = New Collection
    dict(rs!item).Add rs!seller
    rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

There is still the problem of generating a string from a collection. I suggest writing a function that takes a collection and returns a string (called `Join` in the sample below), using one of the two approaches described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29015522/111794).

Once you've done that, you can iterate over the keys in the dictionary, and join the collection in each item:

```
Dim key As Variant
For Each key In dict.Keys
    Debug.Print key, ":", Join(dict(key), ",")
Next
```