# VBA collections - List found items in MsgBox

Tags: arrays, vba, collections, ms-word, msgbox

I was wondering about making a word searcher in a Word document. Previously, all I managed to create is a code that makes it possible to highlight the words I added to a list:

```
Sub example

Dim w(3) as String
Dim k, l as Integer

w(1)= "word1"
w(2)= "word2"
w(3)= "word3"


Set r = Selection
r.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    For k = 1 To 3
        With r.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = w(k)
            For l = 1 To 10
                .Execute Wrap:=wdFindStop, Forward:=True
                     If .Found = False Then
                       Exit For
                     End If
                r.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed
                r.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd
            Next
        End With
      r.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Next
End Sub
```

And it worked perfectly. But my aim was to display all the found words in MsgBox. So I've updated the code:

```
Sub example

Dim w(3) as String
Dim k, l as Integer

w(1)= "word1"
w(2)= "word2"
w(3)= "word3"

Dim wcoll As Collection
Set wcoll = New Collection


Set r = Selection
r.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    For k = 1 To 3
        With r.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = w(k)
            For l = 1 To 10
                .Execute Wrap:=wdFindStop, Forward:=True
                     If .Found = False Then
                       Exit For
                     End If
                r.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed
                r.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd

                wcoll.Add (w(k))

            Next
        End With
      r.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Next

MsgBox("Found words: " & wcoll(1) & " " & wcoll(2) & " " & wcoll(3)) 

End Sub
```

The problem - that I have realized just at the end - is, when the doc contains only 2 of the words searched, but I try to display using the index value `3` as the subscript `wcoll(3)` the MsgBox won't pop up. Instead I get a subscript out of range error. How should I solve this issue, to display all the words (even if there are just the same words)?

Comment: Have a iook to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29015444/how-to-join-a-collection-in-vba - the answer of Vityata shows code you could use

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do it as follows. My addition checks whether the collection `wcoll` contains any members. If it does, the text to show in the `MsgBox` is concatenated. First the static text is assigned, then the members of the collection are looped and the values appended to the string. If there are no members, a default text is assigned.

```
Sub example()    
  Dim w(3) As String, foundWords As String
  Dim k, l As Integer
  Dim wcoll As Collection
  Dim r as Selection

w(1) = "word1"
w(2) = "word2"
w(3) = "word3"

Set wcoll = New Collection        
Set r = Selection
r.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory

    For k = 1 To 3
        With r.Find
            .ClearFormatting
            .Text = w(k)
            For l = 1 To 10
                .Execute wrap:=wdFindStop, Forward:=True
                     If .found = False Then
                       Exit For
                     End If
                r.Range.HighlightColorIndex = wdRed
                r.Collapse Direction:=wdCollapseEnd

                wcoll.Add (w(k))    
            Next
        End With
      r.HomeKey Unit:=wdStory
    Next

    If wcoll.Count > 0 Then
        foundWords = "Found words: "
        For k = 1 To wcoll.Count
            foundWords = foundWords & " " & wcoll(k)
        Next
    Else
        foundWords = "No words were found."
    End If
    MsgBox foundWords    
End Sub
```