# Create dependable dropdown of unique items in vba

Tags: excel, vba

I want to create a dependable drop-down of unique items of `Store` and `Region` from the table in the image below in cells D4 and F4 of Sheet 2, respectively, using VBA. The user first selects the options in the store drop-down in cell D4 and then the dependable region options in cell F4.

I can create unique drop-downs for stores and regions, but they are not dependable. Also, they way I create the unique drop down is not efficient. I record a macro while following the steps in this [article](https://www.xelplus.com/extract-unique-items-for-dynamic-data-validation-drop-down-list/).

[image]

**Edit:** I built the following working solution based on the solution shared by k1dr0ck and the idea of creating the dependable drop-down as the object of the sheet Change event shared by FaneDuru.

1. In a module (Module1), I have the code to create the initial drop-down in `Sheet2` of the workbook using Table `Sales` (in the image above) in `Sheet1`. The `CollectionToArray` function is borrowed from this post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/47500463/18086775

```
Sub Store_Region_dropDown()
  Dim Store As Range, Region As Range
  Dim uniqueStore As Collection, uniqueRegion As Collection
  Dim uniStore As Variant, uniRegion As Variant

  Set Store = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Sales").ListColumns("Store").DataBodyRange

  Set Region = Worksheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Sales").ListColumns("Region").DataBodyRange

   Set uniqueStore = New Colletion
   Set uniqueRegion = New Colletion   

  'Creating a collection of unique items in column store and region
  On Error Resume Next
  For Each cell in Store.Cells
     uniqueStore. Add Cell.Value, CStr(Cell.Value)
  Next Cell
  On Error GoTo 0

  On Error Resume Next
  For Each cell in Region.Cells
     uniqueRegion. Add Cell.Value, CStr(Cell.Value)
  Next Cell
  On Error GoTo 0

  'Converting the collection to an array
  uniStore = Join(CollectionToArray(uniqueStore), ",")
  uniRegion = Join(CollectionToArray(uniqueRegion), ",")

  Sheets("Sheet2").Activate
  Range("D4").Select

  'Creating the data validation list
  'Store-drop-down
  With ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Validation
          .Delete
          .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=uniStore
  End With

  Range("F4").Select
  'Region-drop-down
  With ActiveSheet.Range("F4").Validation
          .Delete
          .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=uniRegion
  End With

End Sub

Public Function CollectionToArray(myCol As Collection) As Variant
    Dim result  As Variant
    Dim cnt     As Long
    ReDim result(myCol.Count - 1)

    For cnt = 0 To myCol.Count - 1
        result(cnt) = myCol(cnt + 1)
    Next cnt

    CollectionToArray = result
End Function
```

2. In `Sheet2`, I'm creating the following object event to update the region drop-down(in cell f4) if the store drop-down (in cell d4) is changed.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim filterTable as ListObject
  Dim Region As Range
  Dim uniqueRegion As Collection
  Dim uniRegion As Variant

  If Target.Address = "$D$4" Then
  
    'Filtering region in sales table based on selected store in cell D4 
    
    Set filterTable = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Sales")
    With filterTable.Range
       .AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:= Range("D4")
       Set Region = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Sales").ListColumns("Region").DataBodyRange.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible) 
    End With 
    filterTable.AutoFilter.ShowAllData

    Set uniqueRegion = New Collection

    On Error Resume Next
    For Each cell in Region.Cells
       uniqueRegion. Add Cell.Value, CStr(Cell.Value)
    Next Cell
    On Error GoTo 0

    uniRegion = Join(Module1.CollectionToArray(uniqueRegion), ",")
  
    Range("F4").Select
    'Region-drop-down
    With ActiveSheet.Range("F4").Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=uniRegion
    End With

  End If
End Sub
```

Comment: Please read the guidance on how to ask a question on SO.

Comment: What you really try accomplishing? Your question is not so clear, at least for me. Since "The user first selects the options in the store drop-down", this means that **the drop down in D4 already exists**. Then, selecting an option in it, you want creating the second dependent one, containing corresponding regions. Would such understanding be a correct one? If so, why do you speak about "unique items"? They looks to be unique, per store, anyhow... Then, shouldn't this creation be the object of a sheet `Change` event, to be done automatically?  Am I missing anything?

Comment: @ FaneDuru The intention is that a user selects the store drop-down in D4. And yes, your understanding of the region drop-down is correct. Yes, it should be an object of a sheet change to be done automatically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please, use the next ways:

1. To build the unique stores validation cell (in "D4"), copy the next code in a standard module:

```
Sub CreateValidationInD4()
   Dim sh1 As Worksheet, sh2 As Worksheet, filterTable As ListObject, arrReg, strFormula As String
   
   Set sh1 = Worksheets("Sheet1")
   Set sh2 = Worksheets("Sheet2")
   
   Set filterTable = sh1.ListObjects("Sales")
       arrReg = filterTable.ListColumns("Store").DataBodyRange.Value2 'place the range in an array
       arrReg = uniqueStores(Application.Transpose(arrReg)) 'extract unique values
       strFormula = Join(arrReg, ",") 'obtain the validation formula string
       
  With sh2.Range("D4").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=strFormula
  End With
End Sub

Function uniqueStores(arr) As Variant 'extract unique strings
    With Application
        uniqueStores = .Index(arr, 1, Filter(.IfError(.Match(.Transpose(.Evaluate("ROW(1:" & _
    UBound(.Match(arr, arr, 0)) & ")")), .Match(arr, arr, 0), 0), "|"), "|", False))
    End With
End Function
```

2. Please, copy the next event code in "Sheet2" code module:

```
Option Explicit

Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
  Dim filterTable As ListObject, arrReg, arrStore, i As Long, arrMatch, k As Long

  If Target.Address = "$D$4" Then
    
     Set filterTable = Sheets("Sheet1").ListObjects("Sales")
 
       arrReg = filterTable.ListColumns("Region").DataBodyRange.Value2 'place the range in an array for faster processing
       arrStore = filterTable.ListColumns("Store").DataBodyRange.Value2

       ReDim arrMatch(UBound(arrReg) - 1) 'redim the formula array at a maximum possible size
       For i = 1 To UBound(arrStore)
            If arrStore(i, 1) = Target.Value Then
                arrMatch(k) = arrReg(i, 1): k = k + 1 'fill the matching array
            End If
       Next i
       
       ReDim Preserve arrMatch(k - 1) 'eliminate the array empty elements
       
       Application.EnableEvents = False 'to avoid running the event twice
        With Me.Range("F4").Validation
            .Delete
            .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Join(arrMatch, ",")
        End With
       Application.EnableEvents = True
  End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

try

```
Sub UniqueList()

    Dim rng As Range, rng2 As Range
    Dim cell As Range, cell2 As Range
    Dim dict As Object, dict2 As Object
    Dim i As Long, j As Long

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
    Set dict2 = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    Set rng = ActiveSheet.Range("A2", ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp))
    Set rng2 = ActiveSheet.Range("B2", ActiveSheet.Cells(ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp))

    For Each cell In rng
        If Not dict.exists(cell.Value) Then
            dict.Add cell.Value, i
            i = i + 1
        End If
    Next cell

    For Each cell2 In rng2
        If Not dict2.exists(cell2.Value) Then
            dict2.Add cell2.Value, j
            j = j + 1
        End If
    Next cell2

    With ActiveSheet.Range("D4").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Join(dict.keys, ",")
    End With

    With ActiveSheet.Range("F4").Validation
        .Delete
        .Add Type:=xlValidateList, AlertStyle:=xlValidAlertStop, Formula1:=Join(dict2.keys, ",")
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: The solution creates the two-drop-down with unique items. Because ```Scripting.Dictionary``` does not work on mac, I used a Collection to add unique items, converted that into an array ```arr```, and then Join( arr ",") to create a data validation list. But ```rng2``` does not depend on ```rng1``` (corresponding regions to a store).